# Difference between Transactional and Reporting Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-warehouse

A friend commented like this:

> I'd recommend separating out your **transactional data** and your **reporting data** into a separate database

And another one told me:

> I would implement an E-R schema in the **transactional data** and a star schema for the **reporting database**

Can anyone make both clear for me? I ask, because I really didn't get difference?

Comment: The "type" of database is generally determined by the operations that need to be performed on it -- are deep analytical queries required or does it need to be fast for updating, etc? Because the data may be overlapping ("duplicated"), having two separate databases (and thus two separate schemes) -- although they could be running in the same database server -- can create a clear separation of concerns and help with maintenance issues.

Comment: I would like to point out that Transactional Data is data that is managed safely ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)); whereas a [Transactional Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_database) can also be a synonym for [Navigational Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigational_database). This does not answer the question, but it's worth the mention.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a [transactional database](http://www.tech-faq.com/transactional-database.html): A transactional database is a DBMS where write operations on the database are able to be rolled back if they are not completed properly.

If a transactional database system loses electrical power half-way through a transaction, the partially completed transaction will be rolled back and the database will be restored to the state it was in before the transaction started.

This is a [reporting database](http://qa.massachusetts.edu/businessintelligence/glossary.html): A database used by reporting applications. Reporting databases are often duplicates of transaction databases used to off-load report processing from transaction databases.

Comment: This is mostly nice. However there is *no reason* why a "reporting database" fails to adhere to ACID. A transactional database refers to the operations and not necessarily that it "has transactions" as per the RDBMS sense.

Comment: oh sorry, it's night here. and I feel stupid. Please, can you give an example for it? Like a small table maybe? Sorry for that...

Comment: transactional data is mission critical data -- customer information, purchases made, date of purchase, item sold, etc. stuff they would need if they were called upon to produce it in court or to the IRS. The data required to make reports that the CEO uses to make decisions (number of sales per day, which items sold and how many of them sold, which items didn't, etc) aren't stored in the main database. They are generated from the info in the main database and put into a separate database so that reporting software can use it and create pretty reports. It's not much, but I hope that helps. :)